# Joomla! model overrides

Tags: php, joomla, overriding

I am developing a Joomla 3.1 website. On the work flow I found out that I need to change administrator/components/com_k2/models/category.xml. I have no other way. But I don't also want my client afterwards to have troubles with K2 updates.

I tried to google about possible solutions but everybody says it is impossible to override models in Joomla. And that I need to make a plugin of it. I am even eager to make a plugin but cannot find appropriate tutorials.

Has anyone met such a problem and is there a way to come to solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to override models: [Plugin Override](https://github.com/juliopontes/joomla-override).

Install and enable the plugin.

You can then copy the file:

```
administrator/components/com_k2/models/category.xml
```

to:

```
administrator/templates/bluestork/html/com_k2/models/category.xml
```

and edit it as you like.

Comment: What have you tried, exactly? Installing and enabling the plugin should allow you to override the model. Please see updated answer above.

Comment: Thank for your answer Emilian, but I install the plugin, enable it then put my category.xml file into the administrator/templates/isis/html/com_k2/models/category.xml (isis is my default template) and it gives me no results.

Comment: I also tried to do the following I read somewhere: administrator/code/isis/code/com_k2/models/category.xml , but this neither gave me results.

Comment: You would also need to copy all the other files to the corresponding directories in the template override, and change the appropriate paths. You would need to start by copying **administrator/components/com_k2/views/category/view.html.php** to **administrator/code/isis/code/com_k2/views/category/view.html.php** and change the corresponding paths (perform a search on "**category.xml**" inside the file, and change the paths to match those in the template folder).